# jqgrid - populate dropdown values for filtering

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I wish to populate dropdown filters in a jqgrid.
[image]

As you can see I want Action status to populate values that come from other database table or any other json.

Can some one help pls?

Comment: I got it working using the FilterTOolbar for Jqgrid http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FillToolbarSearchFilter.htm

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the [FilterToolbar for Jqgrid](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/FillToolbarSearchFilter.htm).